# How to find how much two ranges of time overlap in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this issue regarding overlapping time ranges in excel and I am not precisely sure how to attack the code.

Currently, as shown below, my excel table has various times representing the start and end of certain processes throughout the shop.  These processes may have start and end times that are hours long, or may be a matter of minutes.  What I am trying to do is find whether these processes fall on 1st or 2nd shift, i.e. between 6:00am-4:30pm or 4:30pm-3:00am.

[image: Time Example]

Obviously, the times above would both fall on first shift, but I would like to be able to find out exactly how much of the process falls on each shift, i.e. the code would output that the 1st and 2nd process above would both spend 33 minutes on 1st Shift.

I understand and am not trying to outsource my problem for someone else to code.  I guess I am moreso asking about the validity of using the Intersect function to solve this particular issue.  I know the function can be used to find an intersection of cell ranges, i.e. `Intersect(Activecell, Range("A1:A10"))`, which would output the number of intersecting cells, but I am wondering if the intersect function can be used to find overlapping time ranges as stated above.

I have tried the complicated route of placing code in each cell to calculate long if statements, ex. `=IF(AND(B6<F18,B5>E18), B6-B5, 0)` where B5 and B6 are shown above and E18 and F18 are the start and end of 1st shift, but this is still too simplistic of a view and this is just coding the case where the process falls perfectly into first shift.  To code in every possibility of overlap and variance between process length potentials would be a nightmare.

This is where I am hoping, Intersect will help, though I do not fully understand the entent of its potential nor if it is even the correct function to help my issue.

Hopefully this is more exact. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO is not a code outsourcing platform.  Please post your code and share where within that you need help.  See [the Help Page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more on this.

Comment: DateTime is a very awkward Data Type, and it is so in VBA as well. Time is counted from the 0-time (whatever it is, a few centuries back) and is stored and manipulated internally as a Single Data Type. So, there is no “10:00” or “10:00 AM”, but there is “10:00 AM on such-and-such day of such-and-such Year”---always! More technically, any DateTime is a single-precision decimal with the whole part = [Number of full days since 0-time], and the decimal part = [milliseconds since the midnight in the current day / milliseconds in a day]. How it is displayed/presented is another story, though.

Comment: As an illustration, you can test these in your VBE’s Immediate pane:

    ?(cdate("Jan 1, 2015 10:00 am"))*1.0
    ?(cdate("Jan 2, 2015 10:00 am"))*1.0

Comment: Now it all should be quite simple, I hope :)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
Public Function getShiftMinutes(ByVal pStart As Date, ByVal pEnd As Date, ByVal pShift As Integer) As Long
    Dim dteShiftStart As Date
    Dim dteShiftEnd As Date

    ' determine shift start and end
    If pShift = 1 Then
        dteShiftStart = TimeSerial(6, 0, 0)
        dteShiftEnd = TimeSerial(16, 30, 0)
    Else
        dteShiftStart = TimeSerial(16, 30, 0)
        dteShiftEnd = TimeSerial(3, 0, 0)
        dteShiftEnd = DateAdd("d", 1, dteShiftEnd)
    End If

        ' adjust late hours
    If pStart <= TimeSerial(3, 0, 0) Then
        pStart = DateAdd("d", 1, pStart)
    End If

    If pEnd <= TimeSerial(3, 0, 0) Then
        pEnd = DateAdd("d", 1, pEnd)
    End If

    ' determin if either start or end was in the shift
    If (pStart >= dteShiftStart And pStart <= dteShiftEnd) Or (pEnd >= dteShiftStart And pEnd <= dteShiftEnd) Then
        ' adjust start and end if requiered
        If pStart < dteShiftStart Then
            pStart = dteShiftStart
        End If

        If pEnd > dteShiftEnd Then
            pEnd = dteShiftEnd
        End If

        getShiftMinutes = DateDiff("n", pStart, pEnd)
    Else
        getShiftMinutes = 0
    End If

End Function
```

the first parameter takes the start time, the second one the end time and the third one the shift number

you can test it by something like this:

```
Private Sub test()
    Debug.Print getShiftMinutes(TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), TimeSerial(1, 33, 0), 2)
End Sub
```

and within your worksheet:

```
=getShiftMinutes(A5;A6;1)
```

Comment: depends on the installation ;-) ... here in my Excel the field seperator for formulars is the semikolon ... but you are right ... the code fragments shows that it is coma for the OP

Comment: I'm a little confused by the coding.  You are establishing `pStart as Date` but comparing `If pStart <= TimeSerial(3, 0, 0)`, which is comparing a date and time.  I am getting an answer of 0 because of this.

Comment: within VBA date and time values are stored as double. The part in front of the decimal point represents the days since 1/1/1900 and the part behind the time. 0.25 for example is 6AM on the 1/1/1900. If you keep that in mind you can understand why it is possible to compare date and time ... because both is in real a double value. And if you run the function like in the test() procedure, you will get the right result of 33 minutes

Comment: have you tested the procedure? does it what it should? if not: which result isn't as you expect? That you don't understand how it works does not mean, that it works wrong ;-) and as I said: it works also in the worksheet with the values you have shown in your screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I changed my inputs from simply times, to dates and times according to days of the week.  Thus, I slightly changed the code above to single out specific weekdays that would trigger 1st and 2nd shift.  I also added a Sub() loop to autofill my spreadsheet at the end of the code.  The `Cell.Offset()` codes simply are referring to the `B5` and `B6` cells as above.

Right now, the issue I am facing revolves around the adjustment of the start time and end time if the process begins before the shift or ends after the shift.  Because the `TimeSerial(6, 0, 0)` refers to a 1/1/1900 date rather than the correct raw data date, the calculation is enormously incorrect.  Is there a simple way to format the code to pull in the date from the `pStart` data for the `dteShiftStart` and `dteShiftEnd`?

```
    Public Function getShiftMinutes(pStart As Date, pEnd As Date) As Long
    Dim dteShiftStart As Date
    Dim dteShiftEnd As Date

' determine shift start and end
If Weekday(pStart, 2) >= 1 And _
    Weekday(pStart, 2) <= 4 And _
    (pStart - Int(pStart)) < TimeSerial(16, 30, 0) And _
    (pStart - Int(pStart)) >= TimeSerial(6, 0, 0) Then

    dteShiftStart = TimeSerial(6, 0, 0)
    dteShiftEnd = TimeSerial(16, 30, 0)
Else
    dteShiftStart = TimeSerial(16, 30, 0)
    dteShiftEnd = TimeSerial(3, 0, 0)
    dteShiftEnd = DateAdd("d", 1, dteShiftEnd)
End If


' determin if either start or end was in the shift
If ((pStart - Int(pStart)) >= dteShiftStart And (pStart - Int(pStart)) <= dteShiftEnd) Or ((pEnd - Int(pEnd)) >= dteShiftStart And (pEnd - Int(pEnd)) <= dteShiftEnd) Then
    ' adjust start and end if requiered
    If (pStart - Int(pStart)) < dteShiftStart Then
        pStart = dteShiftStart
    End If

    If (pEnd - Int(pEnd)) > dteShiftEnd Then
        pEnd = dteShiftEnd
    End If

    getShiftMinutes = DateDiff("n", pStart, pEnd)
Else
    getShiftMinutes = 0
End If

End Function
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Shift_Load()
Dim Cell As Range
Sheets("Future_220_140_MON").Select
MsBox = Range("B5").Value

Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Select
LastColumn = ActiveCell.Column
For Each Cell In Range("B18:AJ18")
If IsEmpty(Cell.Value) = True Then
Cell.Value = 0
Else: Cell.Value = getShiftMinutes(CDate(Cell.Offset(-13, 0)), CDate(Cell.Offset(-12, 0)))
End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Scratch that, figured it out.  I could simply add a code to say `dteShiftStart = TimeSerial(6,0,0) + INT(pStart)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Sub test()
Dim firstFrom As Date, firstTill As Date, secondFrom As Date, secondTill As Date
firstFrom = #10:00:00 AM#
firstTill = #3:53:00 PM#
secondFrom = #10:33:00 AM#
secondTill = #11:06:00 PM#

    firstMed = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(firstFrom, firstTill + 1, secondTill + 1)
    secondMed = Application.WorksheetFunction.Median(firstFrom, firstTill + 1, secondFrom)
    countMins = firstMed - secondMed

    MinFormated = Format(countMins, "hh:mm")
    HourToMinInt = Int(Split(MinFormated, ":")(0)) * 60
    MinInt = HourToMinInt + Int(Split(MinFormated, ":")(1))
End Sub
```